# Excel vlookup 3 columns from sheet A and match with the two columns in sheet B, and give 3rd column in sheet B

Tags: excel

I would like to do a vlookup or any function to match data in two sheets (sheet A and sheet B).

This is my sheet A:

[image]

This is my sheet B (Imagine the column is A, B, C, instead of E,F,G in the image):

[image]

I want the answer in sheet B, column C. 
E.g. the result should be like below.

[image]

I tested the function below, but not working.

```
=VLOOKUP($A1+$B1,SheetA!$A:$C,3,FALSE)
```

Comment: yeah. I'm able to do vlookup for 1 column, but not matching two criteria.

Comment: `=INDEX(SheetA!$C$3:$C$6, MATCH(1, (SheetB!E3 = SheetA!$A$3:$A$6) * (SheetB!F3 = SheetA!$B$3:$B$6),0))` and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after typing into formula bar, because it's an array formula.

Comment: =VLOOKUP(SheetB!$A3, SheetA!$A$3:$A$6,3,0) <- not working for me.

Comment: These will only work exactly as written if your sheet names are exactly as you indicated, and your data matches your images, with data starting in row 1 in both sheets.

Comment: Mako212. Yeah! The index works! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula version of `INDEX/MATCH` to match on multiple criteria (you must press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after typing it in the formula bar to make it an array formula):

```
=INDEX(SheetA!$C$3:$C$6, MATCH(1, (SheetB!E3 = SheetA!$A$3:$A$6) * (SheetB!F3 = SheetA!$B$3:$B$6),0))
```

Each set of criteria goes in parenthesis within `MATCH`, separated by `*`, with the value on the left, and the range to match from on the right of the `=` sign.